# Pause lua coroutine from outside function for use in a scheduler

Tags: lua, coroutine

This has been talked about before and all that can be done from the outside it seems is kill the coroutine. This is of course not practical for a scheduler. Is there a way to pause a coroutine from the outside at all or maybe a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the C API, you can [set a hook](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_Hook) that will yield after `$n` lines / instructions.  (This isn't possible through `debug.sethook`, because it adds an in-between layer which prevents it from working.)

You can wrap that up as a single function which you can expose to Lua, so apart from adding that one function, you can do it from Lua.  Example:

```c
static int setyieldhook( lua_State * L ) {
   lua_State * coro;
   int steps;
   luaL_checktype( L, 1, LUA_TTHREAD );
   coro = lua_tothread( L, 1 );
   steps = luaL_optinteger( L, 2, 0 );
   if (steps <= 0) {
      lua_sethook( coro, NULL, 0, 0 );
   } else {
      lua_sethook( coro, yieldhook, LUA_MASKCOUNT, steps );
   }
   return 0;
}
```

and then just push that as a function to Lua and give it a name, e.g. `debug.setyieldhook`.

This one would be used as `debug.setyieldhook( coro, timeout )` and whenever the coroutine runs, it will yield after `timeout` Lua instructions.  To clear, `debug.setyieldhook( coro, 0 )`.  (Note: You cannot change/remove hooks set via `setyieldhook` through `debug.sethook` and vice versa – this will throw an error or silently create a mess.  But you could extend `setyieldhook` to detect & clear "normal" Lua hooks, and/or wrap `debug.sethook` to check for & clear the yield hook.)

Other things to watch out for:

- If the coroutine `yield`s, this will not reset the hook timer.
- The coroutine will yield without returning anything, so you probably want
  to wrap `coroutine.yield` and/or `coroutine.resume` so you can tell apart
  "normal" `yield`s from timeout `yield`s.
- C functions do not count up the number of instructions processed, and so
  will not trigger the hook (e.g. long-running non-greedy string matches via
  `string.*`), so this doesn't provide hard timing guarantees.

Comment: This is a viable option that I can use, but quick question, is there any implementation of this in standard lua that I can use? Perhaps insert the coroutine.yield() into the executing function at certain lines of code intervals? It is a bit of an inconvenience for me to set up C for my environment, but if none exists than I will use the above option

Comment: @Varscott11 Well, you can wrap library functions to increment an internal (shared) counter and occasionally `yield`.  (So you're essentially emulating an OS, where, let's say, all `io`, `os`, … functions _can_ yield if the time is up.)  Or maybe (haven't tried this one) set a normal hook with arbitrary timeout condition that only replaces the global environment or some often-accessed thing with a dummy table with `__index`/`__newindex`. When the metamethod triggers, it changes that back to the normal thing, yields, then (after resume) re-does the hijacked operation on the normal thing.

Comment: @Varscott11 (But that's all hacky and not something you want to rely on for serious use.  That's fine for quick tests and so on, but there's plenty of potential for weird interactions and hard-to-test-for breakage. So do it via C if you want to use this in a library / provide it to others / …)